# How do I view a stack trace or an error report with Aptana, Apache2, and XDebug?

Tags: php, apache2, aptana, xdebug

I set up XDebug with Aptana, Firefox, and Apache2 using PHP. I want to be able to view an error report of some sort whenever the app crashes.

For example, the application quits whenever my require_once() has the wrong file location.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**I figured it out:**

All you need to do is set display_errors = On in the php.ini and it's good!